# Growth over Years in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with `member_id`, `joined` (as in time joined) and I'm trying to figure out how to find percent growth between years.
I have

```sql
SELECT YEAR(joined) AS JoinedYear, COUNT(member_id) AS Members
FROM grp_member 
GROUP BY YEAR(joined) 
ORDER BY JoinedYear asc;
```

this shows the number of people joining per year but need help finding growth using subqueries.

Comment: You really should specify the output format that you are expecting and include some example data for what you have now. There are lots of examples of this type of query if you just do a web search on your title.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS

Comment: Use percent change rules to determine growth.  You can create your own function.  The previous year is a lag of 1

Answer (score 1):

Just use a window function:

```
SELECT YEAR(joined) AS JoinedYear,
       COUNT(*) AS Members,
       (-1 + COUNT(*) * 1.0 / LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(joined))) as growth_rate
FROM grp_member 
GROUP BY YEAR(joined) 
ORDER BY JoinedYear asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search reveals this example from [SQLServerCentral: Getting Year-Over-Year growth data](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/getting-year-over-year-growth-data) It your base query as a CTE and self joins on it to get the previous year value:

```sql
WITH Growth 
AS (
    SELECT YEAR(joined) AS JoinedYear, COUNT(member_id) AS Members
    FROM grp_member 
    GROUP BY YEAR(joined) 
    ORDER BY JoinedYear asc  
)
SELECT curYear.JoinedYear AS [Year], curYear.[Members]
FROM Growth curYear
LEFT JOIN Growth prevYear ON curYear.JoinedYear = prevYear.JoinedYear + 1
ORDER BY curYear.JoinedYear
```

Try it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8a3f7/5

| Year | Members | Year-Over-Year Growth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 3 | 0 |
| 2020 | 6 | 3 |
| 2021 | 9 | 3 |

The overall total members is not included in this output as that should include provision for members that have lapsed or cancelled but this should be a simple primer for more complex needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the `GROUP BY`‌‌‌​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌ operator. The `GROUP_CONCAT` version receives the last 1 month in a result set, so if you've made the expression being subquery you would `SUM` it and then use your join to get the first falling in the highest outer group.